Two $SO(2)$ connections on a smooth $SO(2)$-vector bundle
Let $L\to M$ be a smooth $SO(2)$-vector bundle. We can identify the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ with $i\Bbb R$. Suppose $\nabla, \nabla'$ are two $SO(2)$-connections on $L$ such that $\nabla=\nabla'+iA$ for some $A\in \Omega^1$ with $dA=0$. Further suppose that $H^1(M;\Bbb R)=0$ so that $A=-df$ for some $f\in \Omega^0(M)$, and $\nabla=\nabla'-idf$. Then $\exp(if)$ defines a bundle automorphism $g:L\to L$. Consider the connection $g\cdot \nabla'$ defined by $(g\cdot \nabla')_X(s)=g(\nabla'_X(g^{-1}s))$ for $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and $s\in \Gamma(L)$. Then why does $g\cdot \nabla'=\nabla$ hold? I tried to verify this locally using a local positively oriented orthonormal frame $\{e_1,e_2\}$ of $L$, but I've got, for example, $$(g\cdot \nabla')(e_1)=(-\sin(df)\cos f +\cos(df)\sin f)e_1+(-\sin(df)\sin f -\cos(df)\cos f)e_2 + \nabla' (e_1).$$ What went wrong?

What are $\sin(df)$ and $\cos(df)$ supposed to mean?

@TedShifrin I meant the 1-form on $M$ defined by $v\mapsto \sin(vf)$ for $v\in TM$

That’s not a 1-form, of course.

@TedShifrin I've found that I had a mistake. I thought $d(\cos f)=-\sin(df)$, but in fact $d(\cos f)=-\sin(f) df$.

We have that by the Leibniz rule for covariant derivatives:
\begin{align}
\exp(if)\cdot \nabla'_X(\exp(-if)\cdot s))=&(\exp(if)\cdot s)\cdot d(\exp(-if)(X)+\exp(if)\cdot \exp(-if)\cdot \nabla'_Xs\\
=&(\exp(if)\cdot \exp(-if))\cdot (-idf(X))\cdot s+\nabla'_Xs\\
=&\nabla_X's+iA(X)\cdot s
\end{align}
implying that:
\begin{align}
(g\cdot\nabla')_Xs=\nabla_Xs
\end{align}
